# prefix a friendly url using mod rewrite in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to prefix a htaccess rewrite rule

for example can a variable be used as a prefix to a url

website.com/**$variable**-for-sale/

```
       /cupcakes-for-sale/
       /pies-for-sale/
       /flans-for-sale/
```

The idea is to then use that variable to display all the cupcakes/pies/flans for sale

How would this be written as a rewrite rule? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say but you can create a URL like `domain.com/cupcakes-for-sale/` and a RewriteRule that will internally redirect that URL more specific the word cupcakes to your php file to show the data you want for example to `read.php?recipe=cupcakes`.

Comment: I guess I missed a few things out, new to htaccess so not entirely sure what I had to put. I'll try again hah. I guess i want something like ?cake=cupcakes and then append a -for-sale/ at the end of it so that it will look like cupcakes-for-sale/ or pies-for-sale. Is it possible to rewrite a dynamic url like this? Hope that cleared it up a little @Prix Thanks =)

Comment: I've done editing =) Hopefully it'll help @Prix

Comment: Yes that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule will take care of redirecting your ugly URL to Friendly like one.

The second rule will internally redirect it back so the browser URL remains the friendly URL while service the content of your page.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /?cake=anything to /anything-for-sale/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+\?cake=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-for-sale/? [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /anything-for-sale/ to /?cake=anything
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-for-sale/?$ /?cake=$1 [NC,L]
```

Keep in mind I am using `R=302` its always better to use `302` which means temporary redirect while testing a new rule before making it permanent as the permanent will cache the information to your browser. Once the rule is confirmed to be working as expected change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Answer (score 0):

To extract variable, you need to use regex parentheses in the correct pattern, then you can use `$1` to fetch the group:

```
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-for-sale/$ /target.php?variable=$1 [L]
```

The "target" part is the script you use to display the "variable". Since your question doesn't mention what that is, you have to figure it out.